# How to find array elements that fall in a given interval?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

This is an interview question.

Given an array of integers and a *stream* of intervals (pairs of integers) find the elements of the array that fall in each interval of the stream. What array pre-processing would you use?

Comment: I would personally go with something like bucket sort. Make n buckets where n is the number of intervals. Then in O(n) you would have your result.

Answer (score 9):

One option would be to preprocess the array by sorting it into ascending order.  Once you've done that, you can find all elements that fall within an interval by doing two binary searches over the sorted array - one to find the first element greater than or equal to the start of the interval and one to find the last element no greater than the endpoint of the interval - and then iterate across the array to output all elements in that range.

This requires O(n log n) time to preprocess if you use a standard sorting algorithm like quicksort or heapsort, but can be done in O(n log U) time if you use radix sort (here, U is the largest integer in the range).  Queries then take time O(log n + k) each, where n is the number of elements and k is the number of elements within the range.

If you want to get fancy, you can speed this up exponentially by using a [van Emde Boas tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Emde_Boas_tree), a specialized data structure for storing integers.  If the largest integer value you are working with is U, then you can build the structure in time O(n log log U) and then do the endpoint range searches in time O(log log U).  You can then find all elements in the range in time O(log log U) apiece, giving an O(k log log U) algorithm for finding all matches within a range.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Sort the array, then do binary search to find the indices of the first element in the array that is greater than the interval start, and then again to find the first element that is less than the interval end, and return all the integers in between. It would be `O(log N)` for each lookup where N is the number of integers.

Comment: Isn't this exactly the same as my answer? :-)

Comment: yep, you beat me to it in spite of me writing less :(

Comment: Which is why it's never a crime to be _even more_ explanatory, @HariShankar :-)

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends upon your requirements :

> how many intervals you have say M?

Of course, using M * O(N logN) is overkill, especially when M is large and so are the intervals .

**Another approach :**  using O(N) extra space .

```
prefix[i] = number of numbers in range 0 to i
```

Can be done in O(N) time .

Now, you need O(1) time for each query :

```
query[l,r] = prefix[r] - prefix[l - 1] + 1
```

so total time complexity is `O(N logN  + M)`

Comment: Your answer's always return 1 for any query!

Answer (score 1):

What about indexing the array according to its elements?

```
for (i in original_array) indexed_array[original_array[i]] = original_array[i]

for (j in stream) {
  for (k=stream[j][0]; k<=stream[j][1]; k++) 
    if (indexed_array[k]) return indexed_array[k]
}
```

Or put the indexes instead of the integers:

```
for (i in original_array) indexed_array[original_array[i]] = i
```